# C++ reference pointer as parameter to alter pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference

I've recently come across `*&` as a parameter in a function.
From what I've understood, it is similar to `**`.

Why is it needed in a function that is altering the pointer?
E.g. with the `new` keyword

Let's say I have a pointer `int* a`, why would I have to pass the parameter as a "pointer reference" if I wanted to do `a = new int;` inside that function?

Comment: `int *&` is to `int*` as `int&` is to `int`. There is nothing special about pointers, they just have a funny spelling.

Comment: @molbdnilo haha, that actually made sense. Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the function takes `int*` as its parameter, then the pointer is passed by value itself, that means any modification on the pointer itself (not the pointee) inside the function has nothing to do with the original pointer. e.g.

```
void foo(int* a) { a = new int; }

int* a = nullptr;
foo(a);
// a is still nullptr here
```

If you change the parameter type to `int*&` it'll be different.

```
void foo(int*& a) { a = new int; }

int* a = nullptr;
foo(a);
// a gets modified
```